# Basic practice of dynamic library C++

Tags: c++, gcc, dynamic-linking

I am trying dynamic-linking test.

`mylib.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int hello(){
   cout<<"Hello,World!"<<endl;
   return 1;
}
```

then compile

```
g++ -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.cpp
```

Now there appears the `libmylib.so`

`test.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int hello();
int main() {

    hello();
    std::cout << "Test Finish!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Try to compile with this,

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -L ./
```

There comes the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "hello()", referenced from:
      _main in test-37bd2a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do I need to add some options or are there something wrong in my source code??

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to add some options

yes, link with the library.

```
g++ ... -lmylib
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand -L is for search pass and -l is for name.